# MockMailSender class automatically autowired to MailSender?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, junit

I have implemented MockMailSender as:

```
@Service 
public class MockMailSender implements MailSender {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public void send(SimpleMailMessage message) throws MailException {
        log.info("to: " + message.getTo());
        log.info("subject: " + message.getSubject());
        log.info("body: " + message.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void send(SimpleMailMessage... messages) throws MailException {
        for (SimpleMailMessage message: messages
             ) {
            send(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Good thing is its automatically `@Autowired` to MailSender object in my `@RestController` class. So when I run my code in testing it doesn't actually send email but only Mocks it. But the problem is how can I disable this default behaviour if I want my code in production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple alternatives, maybe you can use [Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) with two MailSender conditioned by a [`@Profile`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) annotation.
Something like this:

```
@Service @Profile("test")
public class MockMailSender implements MailSender {
    //...
}
@Service @Profile("production")
public class ExchangeMailSender implements MailSender {
    //...
}
```

[Here](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/spring-4-conditional-bean-configuration/) an example.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I like the [`@Profile`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) approach. Mark the first service with annotation `@Profile("test")` and create the second implementation of the `MailSender` interface that actually sends email itself.

```
@Service
@Profile("production") 
public class MailSenderImpl implements MailSender {
    // Log & send
}
```

Autowire the service and use it. The advantage is that the right one will be injected conditionally although there exists more beans of same interface:

```
@Autowired
MailSender mailSender;
```

You can configure the current environment (aka profile) with the following configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class EnvironmentConfiguration implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext sc) throws ServletException {
        sc.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active", "test");
    }
}
```

I am not sure how exactly would Spring-Boot manage this configuration. Anyway, I recommend you to read more at [Spring Docs - 25. Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) and about Spring-Boot profiles at [Mkyong's](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-profiles-example/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring profiles and have this bean only available on a profile called "test" for example:

```
@Service
@Profile("test")
public class MockMailSender implements MailSender {
    ...
}
```

Then you can set this profile as active in your unit test class like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class myTestClass
```

Comment: is this method suitable for integration test or only unit test. I am thinking @RestController class that has MailSender member isn't a test class. Sorry if I sound stupid. But can there be a more clean solution through configurations?

Comment: Yes its suitable for integration tests too. You can set the profile through configuration as well instead of using the @ActiveProfiles. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html